# Slow performance of split() function

Tags: r

I have a csv file consisting of around 200.000 rows of transactions. Here is the import and little preprocessing of the data:

```
data <- read.csv("bitfinex_data/trades.csv", header=T)
data$date <- as.character(data$date)
data$date <- substr(data$date, 1, 10)
data$date <- as.numeric(data$date)
data$date <- as.POSIXct(data$date, origin="1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")

head(data)

id          exchange  symbol                date price     amount  sell
1 24892563       bf   btcusd 2018-01-02 00:00:00 13375 0.05743154 False
2 24892564       bf   btcusd 2018-01-02 00:00:01 13374 0.12226129 False
3 24892565       bf   btcusd 2018-01-02 00:00:02 13373 0.00489140 False
4 24892566       bf   btcusd 2018-01-02 00:00:02 13373 0.07510860 False
5 24892567       bf   btcusd 2018-01-02 00:00:02 13373 0.11606086 False
6 24892568       bf   btcusd 2018-01-02 00:00:03 13373 0.47000000 False
```

My goal is to obtain hourly sums of amount of token being traded. For this I need to split my data based on hours, which I did in a following way:

```
tmp <- split(data, cut(data$date,"hour"))
```

However this is taking way too long (up to 1 hour) and I wonder whether or not this is normal behaviour for functions such as `split()` and `cut()`? Is there any alternative to using those two functions?

UPDATE:

After using great suggestion by @Maurits Evers, my output table looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 25 x 2
   date_hour     amount.sum
   <chr>              <dbl>
 1 1970-01-01 00       48.2
 2 2018-01-02 00     2746. 
 3 2018-01-02 01     1552. 
 4 2018-01-02 02     2010. 
 5 2018-01-02 03     2171. 
 6 2018-01-02 04     3640. 
 7 2018-01-02 05     1399. 
 8 2018-01-02 06      836. 
 9 2018-01-02 07      856. 
10 2018-01-02 08      819. 
# ... with 15 more rows
```

This is exactly what I wanted, expect for the first row, where the date is from year 1970. Any suggestion on what might be causing the problem? I tried to change the origin parameter of `as.POSIXct()` function but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Share example data or... (reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: R's `split` function will go in a create a list of data frames, split by whatever column you tell it to use.  Is this what you really want?  Or, do you want something else?  What is your expected output?

Comment: "My goal is to obtain hourly sums of amount of goods being traded." Don't split the data. Use package data.table or package dplyr for their "apply-by-group" functionality.

Comment: You might get a speed up by using `trunc` rather than `cut`

Comment: Relevant answer on different split-apply alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34167477/1851712

Comment: Regarding the 1970 timestamp: perhaps you have a `0` in your file where there should be a timestamp? `.POSIXct(0)` is `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Roland's comment. To illustrate, here is an example.

1. Let's generate some data with 200000 entries in one minute time intervals.

   ```
   set.seed(2018);
   df <- data.frame(
       date = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00"), by = "min", length.out = 200000),
       amount = runif(200000))
   head(df);
   #                 date     amount
   #1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.33615347
   #2 2018-01-01 00:01:00 0.46372327
   #3 2018-01-01 00:02:00 0.06058539
   #4 2018-01-01 00:03:00 0.19743361
   #5 2018-01-01 00:04:00 0.47431419
   #6 2018-01-01 00:05:00 0.30104860
   ```
2. We now (1) create a new column `date_hour` that includes the date & hour part of the full date&time, (2) `group_by` column `date_hour`, and (3) sum entries from column `amount` to give `amount.sum`.

   ```
   df %>%
       mutate(date_hour = format(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H")) %>%
       group_by(date_hour) %>%
       summarise(amount.sum = sum(amount))
   ## A tibble: 3,333 x 2
   #   date_hour     amount.sum
   #   <chr>              <dbl>
   # 1 2018-01-01 00       28.9
   # 2 2018-01-01 01       26.4
   # 3 2018-01-01 02       32.7
   # 4 2018-01-01 03       29.9
   # 5 2018-01-01 04       29.7
   # 6 2018-01-01 05       28.5
   # 7 2018-01-01 06       34.2
   # 8 2018-01-01 07       33.8
   # 9 2018-01-01 08       30.7
   #10 2018-01-01 09       27.7
   ## ... with 3,323 more rows
   ```

This is very fast (it takes around 0.3 seconds on my 2012 MacBook Air), and you should be able to easily adjust this example to your particular case.

Comment: @MetodJazbec ?? Your comment seems to be incomplete (there is limit on the number of characters, and posting extended code or code output in comments is not a good idea anyway); to store the output in a new variable just do `df.new <- df %>% ...` where you include the `magrittr` chain from above. The output table will only include `date_hour` and `amount.sum` as you've summarised data by calculating the sum of `amount` (which means that in this case values in the other columns don't make any sense anymore).

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I added an update to my post so that I could include the output table as well.

Comment: @MetodJazbec It's difficult to debug without your actual data. Check what source entry the `"1970-01-01 00"` row originates from. You should check what date entries give rise to this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute hourly sums without any packages, by using `tapply`. I use the random data as suggested by Maurits Evers:

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(
    date = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00"),
               by = "min", length.out = 200000),
    amount = runif(200000))
head(df)
##                  date     amount
## 1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.33615347
## 2 2018-01-01 00:01:00 0.46372327
## 3 2018-01-01 00:02:00 0.06058539
## 4 2018-01-01 00:03:00 0.19743361
## 5 2018-01-01 00:04:00 0.47431419
## 6 2018-01-01 00:05:00 0.30104860


tapply(df$amount,
       format(df$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H"),
       sum)
## 2018-01-01 00 2018-01-01 01 2018-01-01 02 
##      28.85825      26.39385      32.73600 
## 2018-01-01 03 2018-01-01 04 2018-01-01 05 
##      29.88545      29.74048      28.46781 
## ...
```